# I'm trying to send emails from an AngularJS app based upon a date/firebase value

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, nodemailer

I'm currently working on a site for a client that needs an email reminder to be sent if a database entry is untouched for 2 days.

Example: 
- Referral enters the system and is submitted to firebase

- Documents must the be sent in and uploaded by one of the team. If the files haven't been uploaded within 2 days an email reminder needs to be sent to the relevant people.

I am using Firebase, Express, Node and Angular as well as nodemailer, although I am open to chanbge as I really need to get this working! Any help is much appreciated, I'm really struggling on how to get this to work, so thank you in advance!

Here is the code from my refCollection function that is sending the data to Firebase:

```
materialAdmin.factory('refCollection', ['$rootScope', '$firebaseAuth', 'FIREBASE_URL', '$state', '$firebaseObject', '$http', 'growlService', function($rootScope, $firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL, $state, $firebaseObject, $http, growlService){
  var enqRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'tenants');

  var enqObject = {

    tenantRef: function(user) {

            var enqRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'tenants')
            .push({
                date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                status: "amber",
                refName: user.refName,
                refLastName: user.refLastName,
                refNum: user.refNum,
                refEmail: user.refEmail,
                tenName: user.tenName,
                tenLastName: user.tenLastName,
                tenNum: user.tenNum,
                tenEmail: user.tenEmail
            }); //user info

            // Add UID to lead as a key/value pair
            var enqId = enqRef.key();

            var addIdRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'tenants/').child(enqId).update({
                id: enqId
            });

            growlService.growl('Referral Added!', 'inverse');

        },

    addOwner: function(ref, uid) {
        var noteRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'tenants/' + ref).update({
            dateStatusChanged: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
            owner: uid,
            status: 'green'
        })
    }
}//leadObj
return enqObject;

}]); //factory
```

I need to send an email once that date value in the enqRef variable that is pushing the array to Firebase gets more than 48 hrs ago.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Will do, I'll edit it now

Comment: Question is too broad. Narrow this down to specific problem/question. See [ask]

Comment: AngularJS can't send emails since it is a client script running in the user's browser.  You can, however, send a request to your node server, which could send an email in response to that request.  In fact, if you are trying to do something after a set period of time, then this **definitely** would need to be done on the server side, and really without any request at all from the angular app.  Therefore, I don't think angular is relevant here.

Comment: Set up cron task on server to query overdue items and respond according to results

Comment: Thanks Claies, I had a feeling I needed to do this serverside with the rest of my nodemialer stuff, the issue im having is that I don't know how to write server side code that is checking that date value in firebase and sending an email for each one that is +48hrs

Comment: @charlietfl thanks that sounds like what I'm looking for definitely, could you maybe point me in the direction of some examples or anything?

Comment: Google `node cron` or `node cron task` etc.

Comment: awesome, thank you just reading through the docs now!